# Tensorflow on Android real device seems very slow compared to android emulator or iphone 6s

Tags: android, tensorflow

I'm currently devleoping an android app which recognizes and predicts what they are from series of images.

I referenced android camera example from tensorflow github (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) to implement tensorflow functionality.

Between 150 ~ 250 images are being fed continousely and it works very well when I tested the app in the android emulator bundled with android studio.

it takes less than 1 min (40~60 sec depending on total number of images) to process/predict all the images.

So I installed the apk on real device (LG G5) and fed same images, but it took more than 2 min to finish prediction.

I also tested on iPhone 6s ( iOS app with same functionality is also under development), it took just 40 to 50 sec to finish!

Is this a usual case for android because LG G5 (or other android devices) has far less computation power compared to iPhone 6s or emulator?

**Or is there any workaround to speed up the prediction on android real device?**

---

FYI, my current dev env are:

- MBP late 2013 / Android Studio
- Tensorflow 1.0.1
- put prebuilt JNI libraries and jar libraries from nightly build
- Tested graph files: optimized / quantized graph

Copied TensorflowImageClassifier.java and Classifier.java from Tensorflow demo project and called

```
final List<Classifier.Recognition> results = classifier.recognizeImage(bitmap);
```

in the activity.

Comment: i noticed the same thing using the`object detection API` .. the inference time is way better in emulator than on real device. Did you manage to conclude the cause of it ? was it from the device it self ? I used as an emulator the `Pixel 2 XL` and as real device `Huawei P9 Lite`